# NPSP Refreshing Opportunities Button

Tags: npsp, nonprofit-starter-pack

I am volunteering with a Non-Profit to help them out with their donation management.  We're working on getting 'pledged' donations to be populated from their Recurring Donations.  We are using iATS to process our recurring donations online.  When they are importing updates into Salesforce marking donations as Posted every month - or when the amount changes for their recurring donation - we are not getting the Opportunities refreshed.

Does anyone have experience with this?  Is there a way to schedule this to run (its all hidden NPSP stuff)?

My thoughts right now is we are going through manually and refreshing everything (12 more months, to august of next year).  But, going forward... I could create a Button [Flow] that queries through and grabs those Open recurring donations and adds another month... or something like that?  I don't anticipate that is the best option though, as potential for it to not scale if they bring on more employees and the number of recurring donations rises much higher.

Comment: Hi David, I work at the Salesforce Foundation and can advise you to ask your question in the Power of Us Hub, where the NPSP product team provides direct support: https://powerofus.salesforcefoundation.org/

Comment: Also, the NPSP is all open source and code is available on Github: https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus

Comment: Thanks Greenstork!  I'll go post that over there.  And thats good to know its on Github!